# Как остановить задачу в самой задаче на определенное время в Quartz.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке, как остановить задачу в самой задаче?
Т.е., если нет данных, которые задача может обработать - подождать 30, например, минут, а потом завестись снова.
Делать await Task.Delay(30 * 60 * 1000) как-то уж совсем не хочется

Использую .net 7 web-api

Comment: это какая то одноразовая задача или задача, которую надо запускать каждые 30 мин?

Comment: Задача вызывается постоянно каждые 5 секунд, сейчас, а надо, чтобы она вызывалась как обычно через 5 секунд, но, если при каких-то условиях нет данных для обработки этой задачи - запустить в следующий раз её через 30 минут

Comment: `await Task.Delay(30 * 60 * 1000)` - почему нет? `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)` можно, если перемножать кажется некрасивым. И да, "раз в 30 минут" и "на 30 минут один раз" - есть разница, использовать или нет Quartz.NET здесь, это вопрос требований.

Comment: Как-то странным выглядит, на мой взгляд, этот await Task.Delay, всё же мне кажется, что можно как-то триггер задачи изменить, но как - не понимаю пока, в документации ничего похожего не нашел :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16334411/5045688

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю, если будет то, что нужно - оформлю ответ с готовым кодом

Comment: Вот ещё: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41590551/5045688. В общем, искать по терминам reschedule job.